# Problem in Inserting or Updating in many to many relationship EF4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, many-to-many

Let's say have 3 tables:

```
Category
-------------
CategoryID    int
Title         text


Admin
------------
AdminID       int
FullName      text


Permission
------------
CategoryID    int
 AdminID      int
 AllowAccess  bit
```

When i try to update changes to database i got following exception:

```
Unable to insert or update an entity because the principal end of the 'KiaNetModel.FK_Permissions_Admins' relationship is deleted.
```

**WHY?**

The function that update changes:

```
public static void SetPermissions(int[] cats, int userId, Entities context)
        {
            var premissions = from p in context.AdminPremissions where p.AdminID == userId select p;
            // Clear all premissions...
            foreach (var p in premissions)
            {
                p.AllowAccess = false;
            }

            foreach (var c in cats)
            {
                var es = from e in context.AdminPremissions where e.CategoryID == c && e.AdminID == userId select e;
                // If any pre permission was found, set flag = true
                if (es.Count() > 0)
                    es.First().AllowAccess = true;

                // Otherwise add new one
                else
                    context.AdminPremissions.AddObject(new AdminPremission() { AdminID = userId, CategoryID = c, AllowAccess = true });
            }
        }
```

It's an web application, and when user mark permissions, i could only determine which permissions are set, not all of them.

If you have any other idea, or better way please tell me.

Answer (score 1):

I think relationship between tables Permission and  Admin has been deleted from either Actual database or from Entity Model. It it is the case then u have to create that relationship again.

Comment: Neither of relationships was deleted. I look at database relation and model, both of them exists.

Answer (score -3):

Generate "Admin" Table And "Permission" Drop And Create Script (With Data - If U Have Data On it).

Then Execute It, If U Have Relation Re Create It,
Ur Prb Must Be Solve.

Comment: As i say in other answer's comment, neither of relationships was deleted :|

Comment: the foreach is the culprit, you can update properties, and add new objects to the Context in the foreach, just be sure you don't call SaveChanges() inside the loop, otherwise you get this error